# Rabbitmq Web Management Console bad performances

Tags: plugins, rabbitmq, rabbitmqadmin, rabbitmq-management

i'm facing serious issues with RabbitMQ Management Plugins: the console has slowness/unresponsiveness issues during some stress test i am running (total throughput ~ 20000 msg/sec split by 10 queues)

Do you have any best practise in order to optimize this console?

Thanks

Refreshing the webpage is quite useless since i need real time statistics.

Comment: RabbitMQ version? Erlang Version? How is the Server CPU and memory? "20000 msg/sec " does not say too much. It depends on what kind of queues you use... if it is in a cluster or not.